# Different behaviour of prepareForSegue and tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios5, uitableview, segue

I am testing a simple scenario that has a UITableViewController that has the cell segue to another UIViewController. Now during that segue, I need to pass some information to the UIViewController such as name and price of an item. I wanted to test the difference between using prepareForSegue and didSelectRowAtIndexPath: to pass those 2 data points. It seems to work with the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: but not prepareForSegue. After doing some debugging:

1-I am wondering if prepareForSegue happens before any IBOutlet on the destinationViewController are initialized and so you can't effectively set them. So prepareForSegue seems to be more geared towards passing non-IBOutlet properties.

2-If I am using a regular push segue, how can I access the "segue.destinationViewController" from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method.

PS: When testing the prepareForSegue, I am setting the segue in IB to push and when testing the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, I am setting the segue in IB to modal.

PS: All resemblances to real names are incidental!

```
   -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"itemDetailSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        NSString *theItemName=[[self.itemsForSale objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSString *theItemPrice=[[self.itemsForSale objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Price"];

        JuanDetailVC* juanDetailVC= (JuanDetailVC*) segue.destinationViewController;

        juanDetailVC.itemName.text=theItemName;
        juanDetailVC.itemPrice.text=theItemPrice;
    }
}


-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *theItemName=[[self.itemsForSale objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *theItemPrice=[[self.itemsForSale objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Price"];

    JuanDetailVC* juanDetailVC= (JuanDetailVC*) self.presentedViewController;

    juanDetailVC.itemName.text=theItemName;
    juanDetailVC.itemPrice.text=theItemPrice;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that you cannot set outlet properties in prepareForSegue. You'll have to pass the properties into another property, then in viewDidLoad of the destination view controller set the outlet's property. For example: you can't set the text of a label, you'll have to create a second property (e.g., an `NSString *labelText`) and in viewDidLoad set the label's text (`self.label.text = self.labelText`).

You don't have access to the destination view controller in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath. You'll have to create the instance yourself by alloc/initing it.

Comment: thanks. On the second point, if I have to alloc/init the instance of the destination view controller, I am guessing I will have to push it on the Nav Controller as well. If that is the case, then it really defeats the purpose of the push segue on the storyboard. So does this mean that in general, you only use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method (versus prepareForSegue) if 1) you are segue to a modal viewcontroller (like I did) or 2) you are segue to a popover 3)or maybe on iPad where you are accessing the detail view controller. In other words, your destination is really the last Scene.Thanx

Comment: While I'm sure there are cases in which it's easier to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I can't think of any right now. I think I pretty much always use prepareForSegue.